# Selenium Web Driver can't connect with Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to configure connection between C#, nUnit test and Selenium Firefox web driver. My code is simple:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Fact]
    public void Bar()
    {
        FirefoxBinary Binary = new FirefoxBinary("C:\\program files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        FirefoxProfile firefoxPro = new FirefoxProfile();
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(Binary, firefoxPro, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 30));
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

During creation of FirefoxDriver object it throws the exception:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:7055

Firefox is opening, but after the exception is thrown.

What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've added inbound and outbound "allow" rules for the port used by Firefox (tried both UDP and TCP), with no positive result. By the way - my OS is Windows Server 2012.

Moreover when I run test second time, while instance of Firefox has already opened another exception is thrown:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Comment: firewall rule getting on the way?

Comment: @KirilS. Thank you for suggestion Kiril - I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested check your firewall rules and that port 7055 is open. It may not be.

We need to know a little more about how you are attempting to run the site - is it via the inbuilt web server on Visual Studio or do you have a local IIS installed?

Comment: Thank you for help. Opening ports haven't helped. In general I'm running on local IIS, but this particular code is executed by Visual Studio test runner.